# Break an integer and insert into an array in specific order

Tags: php, arrays, tokenize

I have a variable that stores a number, let's say `$num = (double)758341`. I wan to break the `$num` and then insert into an array in ascending or descending order. I am just confused how a number will be broken or tokenized.

Comment: Do you want to break it into array of digits? What do you mean by "break it"

Comment: break it means that i want to split it. like 7,5,8,4,3,1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
$num = (double)758341;

$array = str_split($num);

sort($array);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 5
    [4] => 7
    [5] => 8
)
```

Answer (score 0):

use modulus function which gives remainder like

```
  i=0
  while (num > 0)
  {
    arrayName[i++] = num % 10;
    num = num/10;
  }
```

and sort the array as you wish....

Answer (score 0):

```
function split_sort_num($num, $order='asc'){
    $arr = str_split($num);
    if ($order=='asc'){
       sort($arr);
    }
    else{
       rsort($arr);
    }
    return $arr;
}


$num = (double)758341;
$asc = split_sort_num($num);
$dsc = split_sort_num($num, 'desc');
print_r($asc);
print_r($dsc);
```